# Disable drag and drop part in Eclipse e4

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm writing an E4 application with drag dropping of parts. Now I need to disable drag and drop on one part. So that part need always be on that part stack.

Is their some solution for this. I searched already on the internet to a solution but found only "IPresentationEngine.NO_MOVE" but that doesn't work on the part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IPresentationEngine.NO_MOVE` is the correct thing to use.

`IPresentationEngine.NO_MOVE` is a string with the value `NoMove`. To stop a part being moved you add that string to the Tags second of the part description in your Application.e4xmi file.

[image]

You can also set the tag programmatically if you want to turn this on or off.

Comment: On a site note: This is also true for other MUIElements. I for myself searched for a way to disable drag'n'drop for toolbars and could just go with the `NoMove` tag as well.